# KNN parameter tuning with cross validation: score draw

Tags: cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to use the KNN method for binary classification. When trying to find the best 'k' parameter (the amount of neighbours that the algorithm looks at) I train a model on my training set and look at its accuracy on a seperate validation set I got with my data.
This validation set only has 12 samples, which causes a draw in accuracy for 3 k's (1,3,5).

Now I'm looking for a way to choose one of these 3 k's for the definitive model. I had the following approach in mind: for the 3 k's, I do K-fold cross validation for a certain K on the training set and then look which one has the best average accuracy here. Is this a decent approach, or are there better options? I also thought of just picking a random k (1, 3 or 5), because the 'validation procedure' tells me that I can choose any of the 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem occurs when you have a small test set, which can cause multiple models to *tie*, by achieving the same number of correct predictions.

The method you said first should do. Because in CV each model sees each training sample once, I'd consider it unlikely for your 3 models to have the same accuracy. If this persists, it is safe to choose at random (I'd go for 3 because it is the middle element)

Answer (score 1):

Occam's principle suggest's that you should go for the simplest model possible. So you should go for that one. But to get a better idea of the model's generalization, i would suggest you to use nested cross validation.